# Handling List values separately

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, custom-list

In simple words, I have a fully customized webpage in which I would like to show up the information I already entered into a List.

Let's say I have 3 fields on that list ('ID', 'Description' and 'More info'), and I want to show them up with a personalized style and layout, so I need to gather the values separately and not with the whole view (like SP does).

I've found in this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms425858.aspx , that with C# you can do it. But currently I rather keep it with client-side programming.

This is my code so far, but I'm only able to print out the field names and not the values:

```
     function retrieveListItemsInclude() {

        var siteUrl = '/mysite/';
        var viewName = 'My_View';
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('My List');
        var oView = oList.get_views().getByTitle(viewName);
        this.collListItem = oList.getItems(oView);
        var listFields = oView.get_viewFields(); 
        context.load(listFields);
        context.executeQueryAsync(printFieldNames,onError);
    }

    function printFieldNames() {
          var e = listFields.getEnumerator();
          var listItemInfo = '';
          while (e.moveNext()) {
             var fieldName = e.get_current();
             listItemInfo += fieldName + ", ";
          }
          alert(listItemInfo.toString());
       }

       function onError(sender,args)
       {
          alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

       }
```

I'll appreciate the help you can give me on this. Regards!!!

Comment: If you are SP2013 or higher search for everything CSR - Client Side Rendering by Andrei Markeev, especially his Cisar Chrome Extension for developing custom ListViews

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I'll for it and see if I can make usage of that extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach that you used requires two requests to server (the first one to get the view details, and the second one to get the data). You can skip this if you know the column names and the conditions for retrieving the data.
You can try the following code (I modified your code and included the names of the columns that you mentioned in question):

```
function retrieveListItemsInclude() {       
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("My List");       
    var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    var queryResults = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    context.load(queryResults,'Include(More_x0020_info,Description)');
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, function () { printFieldNames(queryResults); }),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onError1)
    );
}

function printFieldNames(listFields) {
      var e = listFields.getEnumerator();
      var listItemInfo = '';
      while (e.moveNext()) {
         var currentItem = e.get_current();
         var moreInfo = currentItem.get_item('More_x0020_info');
         var description = currentItem.get_item('Description');
         var id = currentItem.get_id();
         console.log(id + " - " + moreInfo + " - " + description);
      }
   }

function onError1(sender,args)
{
  console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Damjan. Yeah maybe my approach was not the best one cause I'm starting with Sharepoint. Besides the fact that for some reason the SP.ClientContext.get_current() method doesn't work for me, everything worked perfectly!